# Not returning a component on button press in React-Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am a beginner in the react-native framework. I am building an sample mobile application. And I am stuck at the very basic step.
I am trying to call 'getBusinessNews()' function on click event, which will return a  component. But due to some reason, it's not returning. 
I have doubled checked the path of the component and its correct.
Even the console.log defined inside the function is getting displayed.
I am attaching the code, all kind of help is appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Text,View,TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';        
import BusinessNews from '../News/BusinessNews';
class categories extends Component{ 
   render(){
      return(
          <View>
             <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.getBusinessNews.bind(this)}>
                <Text>Business News</Text>
             </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
       );
   }

   getBusinessNews(){ 
       console.log(1);
       return(      
         <BusinessNews />
       );
    }

   export default categories;
```

Comment: What do you mean by `it's not returning`? The result returned from `getBusinessNews` will not be used in the rendering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Returning component from `event handler/listener` to render will not work.
Instead do `state update` to decide whether component `BusinessNews` will render or not.

Its should do  like this.

**constructor**

```
constructor() {
  this.state = {
    showBusiness: false//initially set to false
  }
}
```

**getBusinessNews**

```
getBusinessNews() {
  this.setState({showBusiness: true})//set to true to show BusinessNews
}
```

**render**

```
render() {

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={this
          .getBusinessNews
          .bind(this)}>
          {this.state.showBusiness ===true && <BusinessNews/>}//check boolean true 
          <Text>Business News</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: Hello Riyaz, thanks for the reply. The above code is working, But its displaying entire component above 'Business News'. I want the component to open like a new page

Answer (score 1):

You can return a component on click. As you have to returns component in **render()** only. You need to change the logic to render component.

You can call `<BusinessNews />` in somewhere in `render()` to add component.